# Al inspeccionar cualquier web y recargar la página se pierde la conexión

Tags: google-chrome, conexión

Hola que tal vengo con un problema que dudo que sea de código pero espero que me podáis echar una mano porque no le estoy encontrando solución.
Cuando inspecciono una página, sea la que sea, en google chrome, **y estando el inspector abierto**, recargo la web y de repente pierdo la conexión a internet, o se buggea completamente y me aparece por ejemplo google así en vista móvil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto solo ocurre con el inspector abierto, si lo quito, y vuelvo a recargar la página, recarga correctamente.**
He actualizado google chrome por si era eso e incluso windows, pero no lo soluciona. ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando con el navegador?
Inspecciono la consola en busca de errores pero o está limpia o son errores de las webs en particular que no tienen nada que ver con el problema como tal.
Esto también pasa si inspecciono mi localhost mientras estoy desarrollando cualquier cosa, lo cual lo hace tremendamente molesto el desarrollo.
¿Puede ser alguna configuración de chrome la que produce el fallo, o alguna cosa de caché?

Comment: La respuesta se pone abajo, como respuesta. Puedes incluso votarla como aceptada después. No se cambia el título de la pregunta. Mueve el texto que añadiste al campo de abajo Tu Respuesta. Te podemos votar positivo y todo

Answer (score 0):

**EDITO, IMPORTANTE:**

Ya vi el problema, y es tan tontísimo el error que me apetece borrar el post pero no lo voy a hacer por si a alguien le ocurre algo parecido.

Tenía puesto en el inspector cuando pongo la vista móvil en lugar de sin limitaciones, lo tenía como personalizada, que de alguna forma tomaba el valor sin conexión, y esto hacía pues efectivamente, que al recargar no se tuviera conexión ninguna.

Estaba ya mirando las IP, los puertos... Incluso valoré un formateo por si tenía algún virus o algo, madre mía jaja

Un saludo.